# Permission denied only when using "sudo su -c"

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, scripts, sudo

I am currently trying to run a script as a different user than the user I am logged in.

I would like to run as `main` user the following command, to have the user `local` executing the script:

`sudo su local -c "/home/main/some/folders/script"`

But I have a `Permission denied` output.

Still, if I log in as local using `sudo su local` and then run the script, everything goes fine.
The permission on the file are `775 main main` and user local is part of the group `local main`

What could be the reason for this, and how to solve it ?

Thanks

Comment: And if you do `sudo -u local /home/main/some/folders/script`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the user local have permissions to access the folders in the path to the file?  Just because it has permissions on the file doesn't mean it can access the file.

as user main, try

```
su local
<enter password>
touch /home/main/some/folders/script
```

To solve it, you'll need to 
`chmod g+rx`  each directory in the path

(Note that to run a script, the user doesn't actually need read permissions, on a directory, just execute permissions.)

Comment: It worked, I thought I just needed to add the containing folder. Thank you very much !